# C# asp.net - Repeaters Collections of text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Assume that I have a list of the following:

```
First Name   Last Name 
Bob          Wonder 
Helen        Wood
...,         ....,
```

I can use a repeater and bind the source to this in asp.net but I am doing this as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" EnableVIewState="true" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLstNumber" runat="server" EnableVIewState="true" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Then I just bind these from a list of contacts. The problem that I am having is that I need to update the records in XML which looks like the following:

```
<Contact name="Bob" lastName="wonder">
```

The problem that I am having is that I do not understand how I would associate the two text boxes so that they relate to each other so then I can just update the XML? For example, if "Bob" changed his last name, I would then update "Bob" in the XML?

Answer (score 1):

You need some Field/Column of your data as primary key or ID, like numbers 1,2,.. and these are not going to change.

However, for just updating contacts, will use the contact index as identification.

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    Last name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLstNumber" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" 
        onclick="SaveButton_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) readxml();

    }

    private void readxml()
    {
        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("contacts.xml"));
        var xmlnodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Contact");

        repeater1.DataSource = xmlnodes;
        repeater1.DataBind();

        xmldoc = null;
    }

    protected void repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

        var node = (XmlNode)e.Item.DataItem;  
        var txtName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtName");
        txtName.Text = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
        var txtLstNumber = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtLstNumber");
        txtLstNumber.Text = node.Attributes["lastName"].Value;
    }

    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("contacts.xml"));
        var xmlnodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Contact");


        for (var i = 0; i < repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = repeater1.Items[i];
            var txtName = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtName");
            var name =  txtName.Text ;
            var txtLstNumber = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtLstNumber");
            var lastName = txtLstNumber.Text;

            var node = xmlnodes[i];
            node.Attributes["name"].Value = name;
            node.Attributes["lastName"].Value = lastName;
        }

        xmldoc.Save(Server.MapPath("contacts.xml"));
        xmldoc = null;
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Contact name="bob" lastName="jan" />
  <Contact name="john " lastName="doe" />
</root>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm not allowed to do this, isn't there an alternative way? I was thinking about maybe having a "on_changed" event which stores the changed values in a session?

Comment: Hey - The user can change his first and last name

Comment: can user add or delete records ?

Comment: Hey - Yes, but, I haven't got around to that functionality just yet. I'm just confused about updating the records now..